# Mongoose populating batch of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with references for population inside a sub-document.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    references: {
        images: [{ref: 'Page', type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
        files: [{ref: 'Page', type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
    }
});
```

And then create a model for it, matching the name of the references (pages => pages).

```
var Page = mongoose.model('Page', schema);
```

I want to retrieve a page by its identifier and retrieve all references.

```
Page.findById(id)
    .populate('references.images') // Err.. two populations..
    .populate('references.files') // Err.. two populations..
    .exec(function(err, page) {
    // ... snip ...
});
```

Now I am doing multiple populations. How can I ensure that a single population loads the batch of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 3.6 pre-release it is possible to do:

```
Page.findById(id)
    .populate('references.images references.files')
    .exec(function(err, page) {
    // ... snip ...
});
```